# Hive query returns wrong answer when executed thru spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Anyone care to hazard a guess why a query executed in both Hive and with Spark's dataframe API returns different results (the answer returned from Hive is the correct one by the way)
Hive:

`gb-slo-svb-0019:10000 > select count(*) from sseft.feat_promo_prod_store_period;
INFO - > select count(*) from sseft.feat_promo_prod_store_period
_c0
84071294`

Spark:

`sqlContext.sql('select count(*) from sseft.feat_promo_prod_store_period').show()
+---+
|_c0|
+---+
|  0|
+---+`

Interestingly if I point to the underlying hdfs location using spark rather than the hive table I get the correct answer: 

`sqlContext.read.parquet('/Lev4/sse/hive/sseft/feat_promo_prod_store_period').count()
84071294`

This image depicts all three:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to determine what causes that behaviour is to look at `explain()` results. Compare these:

```
sqlContext.sql('select * from sseft.feat_promo_prod_store_period').explain()
sqlContext.read.parquet('/Lev4/sse/hive/sseft/feat_promo_prod_store_period').explain()
```

If they are not the same you should look on how the table is created, for example `sqlConext.sql('show create table sseft.feat_promo_prod_store_period').first()`

Comment: This seems to have been a problem with the metadata that spark caches about the table - that theory is based on the fact that dropping the table and recreating it solved the problem. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem unfortunately, if I come up with a repro I'll try and remember to come back here and report it.

Answer (score 0):

check your hive-site.xml, it should be copied to spark conf directory and it should have the following configuration.

```
<configuration>
  <property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://host.xxx.com:9083</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```